# Failing to deploy spring-boot WAR to Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, tomcat8

I'm having trouble deploying my WAR file to elastic beanstalk (Tomcat). I've downloaded the logs and I'm getting a bunch of errors https://pastebin.com/bVTjLJDD

I tested this WAR file successfully with Apache Tomcat deployed locally on my PC, so I don't know what is causing these errors.

My pom.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>io.johnnathan.springboot</groupId>
    <artifactId>product-store</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>product-store</name>
    <description>Product storefront using Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>

        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.3</version>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>

        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.12</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->

        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.8.RELEASE</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->

        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>   
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I've extended SpringBootServletInitializer in the main class. As seen in pom.xml I also set the  tag for the tomcat dependency. Everything works fine when tested on the local Apache Tomcat server. What could be the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultValidator' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/validation/ValidationAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.valueextraction.ValueExtractorManager

Might be because of this, the war is not deployed.

Make sure you have all the libraries in place while making the WAR.

Please check the library is used only for compile or something.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with my pom.xml. The WAR runs just fine when running on my local Apache Tomcat.

Comment: Not sure but the jar might be present in your classpath. Also how you are creating a jar? If by using any tool, please check the settings for the project from where you can set the path for the available jars.

Comment: It was one of the dependencies causing it, I don't know what. I got frustrated with it and just decided to start the project from scratch (I wasn't too far into it) this time using a sample "Hello World" project as a base. Should have tested if the webapp deployed properly on Apache Tomcat before actually doing any coding.